# I want to connect from my pgAdmin to ALLoyDB

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, pgadmin, google-alloydb

I want to connect from my pgAdmin in my local pc to ALLoyDB in a GCP VPC  and i can't find the way

I have read about AlloyDB AuthProxy but I'm still not convinced on the steps to follow or if it's even possible

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

AlloyDB doesn't currently provide a way to easily connect to it from outside the VPC network where it lives. There is a documentation page dedicated to helping folks do what you're trying to do:

https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/connect-external

From those pages:

The solution is going to look like one of the following:

Using Cloud VPN or Cloud Interconnect to merge your local network with the Cloud private network.

Set up an intermediary VM that lives in the same network as the AlloyDB cluster, and setting up one of several options like IAP (Identity Aware Proxy), SOCKS proxy or a PostgreSQL pooler (e.g. PgBouncer) paired with the Auth Proxy running on the VM.

More detailed instructions can be found on the link I provided.